# Get edge position in uv layout

Tags: python, uv

I want to get the per-edge position in uv mask,The position here refers to the x, y coordinates(in image coordinate system) of a series of pixels forming an edge,for example:
Assume we get a unwarped uv map like below:
[image]

That uv map has 31378 edges and the resolution is 500*500,The output of what I want is:

A list that length is 31378, assume its called edge_index_500,each element of edge_index_500 is combined by two array,array 1 store x coordinate of the serials of pixels that form a edge,where array 2 store y coordinate in correspondence.

How to implement that with python script?

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what you tried and didn't work ?

Comment: Actually I am quiet new to blender python API ... I even do not know the basic procedure of how blender python script running...